# Removing all data Except Certain text using Regex

Tags: python, r, regex, xquery

I am trying to remove all words from a string except certain words, for example I want to retain 'red' and 'black' including all combinations it has and remove all other strings.

For example
inputstring = "red => white => green => black,magenta"
outputstring = "red => black,magenta"

I have tried to replace string using regex pattern as = "^red|^black" but it does not change anything in the string.

I am using X query and am unable to figure out pattern to be used in Regex
`let $pattern := "^red|^black" let $pattern := "" let $y := replace($inputstring,$pattern,$replacement)`

Comment: `r` or `python`? (Tags indicate both, code indicates the latter). Btw, In `R`, you could do something like: `text |> strsplit("=>") |> lapply(trimws) |> lapply(\(x) paste(x[grep("red|black", x = x)], collapse = " => "))`, tested with `text <- c("red => white => green => black,magenta", "red => blue => yellow => black,magenta")`.

Answer (score 1):

I would maybe create new string. I mean you do not have to remain the original one. You can simply look for words and their order.

I am not experienced with xquery but I could help you with idea at least.

What do I mean by that. If I understand you correctly then your input string contains `=>` pattern indicating next word. So if yes I would solve it like this:

```
words_list = input_string.split(' => ')
output_list = list()
for one_word in words_list:
   if one_word in ['red', 'black', any_other_wanted_colors]:
      output_list.append(one_word)

output_string = ' => '.join(output_list)
return output_string
```

Answer (score 0):

In R, extract all instances containing “red” or “black”, then concatenate these back together with `" => "` as a separator:

```
library(stringr)
  
x |>
  str_extract_all("\\S*(red|black)\\S*") |> 
  sapply(str_c, collapse = " => ")
# "red => black,magenta"
```

Note this is vectorized, so can also process a vector of multiple input strings.

Answer (score 0):

In XQuery 3.1 (or XPath 3.1) I would do

```
$input 
 => tokenize('\s?=>\s?') 
 => filter(matches(?, 'red|black'))
 => string-join(' => ')
```